# How can I see the challenges of each club?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I want to get the trophy "In Good Standing" and for that I need to complete all the challenges of at least one club. Every time I complete one the screen pops out some notifications that inform me what challenges are left to do. But they are too many to remember.

Is there a way to see them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By going to the Map menu, there, under the icon below the icon of the map (shaped as an open book) you'll find all your "side quest", the clubs challenges, the explorers's missions, club quests, missions to acquire items for citizens and more.

[image]

Comment: I've been searching for this forever in the DNA Tracker where it just says "perform the tasks for this club". Why would they hide it in the map section? Ha!

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Go to the Map screen and open up the **Logbook**.  You will find a list of all the different factions and their respective challenges.